# JxBrowser: How to implement 'save link as' within a ContextMenuHandler

Tags: jxbrowser

I want to implement a 'save link as' option within a ContextMenuHandler.

But there is no browser function like loadURL(...) to force the Browser component to just start a download for the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

__________________ EDITED__________________________

```
  import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.ContextMenuHandler;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.ContextMenuParams;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.SavePageType;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


    public class ContextMenuSample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

            Browser browser = new Browser();
            BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(700, 500);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            browser.setContextMenuHandler(new MyContextMenuHandler(view));
            browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
        }

        private static class MyContextMenuHandler implements ContextMenuHandler {

            private final JComponent component;

            private MyContextMenuHandler(JComponent parentComponent) {
                this.component = parentComponent;
            }

            private static JMenuItem createMenuItem(String title, final Runnable action) {
                JMenuItem reloadMenuItem = new JMenuItem(title);
                reloadMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        action.run();
                    }
                });
                return reloadMenuItem;
            }

            public void showContextMenu(final ContextMenuParams params) {
                final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

                final Browser browser = params.getBrowser();
                popupMenu.add(createMenuItem("Save As", new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Browser browser2 = new Browser();
                        browser2.loadURL(params.getLinkURL());
                        browser2.saveWebPage(params.getLinkText(), ".", SavePageType.COMPLETE_HTML);
                    }
                }));

                final Point location = params.getLocation();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        popupMenu.show(component, location.x, location.y);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this example is not working. No Popup. But i try'ed the browser2 part and it is not working too. Especially with PDF's.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I have edited my answer, the context menu can be called now.

Comment: I try'ed it, but it's not working. You call saveWebPage right after loadURL, but the browser may be not finished to load the webpage at that time. So nothing will be saved. To work around you have to add a LoadListener to browser2 and save the page onFinishLoadingFrame. I added it to the code.

Comment: This does not work as desired. If you 'save a link' to a PDF or an image, the PDF or the image is not saved, but an chrominum generated HTML file (with a link) to view this file. But i want to save the Content (PDF or Image).

Comment: simple. from the output it self we do manually parsing whether it is a file or not, if so... then take a screencapture and save it bravo!